# iframe for app for web users but responsive to mobile users?

Tags: iframe, facebook-canvas

I am building a Facebook web app, http://www.beerwhich.com, and currently have it set to display the app within the Facebook iframe.

That said, I was wondering if I can do one of two things:

1. Get rid of the iframe for phones viewing the web app, and specify mobile-specific styles to the app.
2. Keep the iframe but still detect if the user is viewing the web app on their phone, so I can specify mobile-specific styles

Any mobile/responsive web app advice for iframed apps would be very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

After you do the authentication you need to do, for example set a cookie with JS SDK, than you can redirect your app wherever you want, and use that cookie for info

Even if you do nothing, this will work by itself, to check this, you can right click any app and say "Open Frame in Another Tab" you will see that the application work out of Facebook too